# firebase AnimatedList dbRef error undefined name

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

[image]

dbRef error please help me whats problem is this
query dbRf undefined name why?

Answer (score 0):

`listItem` is a method inside your class, therefore when you declare a variable inside that method then that variable which is in this case `dbRef` is only accessible from that method.

If you want to access `dbRef` in multiple methods, then you need to add it as an instance variable to the class.

You can read this documentation to understand more:

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour